# Extracted Quality Attributes from user stories

Tags: nlp, spacy

How can I Extract Quality Attributes from user stories by using a .csv file in the spacy library and NLP? In CSV file, column 1 contains 2000 user stories.

Comment: What are "quality attributes"?

Comment: Software quality attributes.  like security, safety etc.